# Folder Dialog in PyQT5

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I want to create a Python Plugin for QGIS 3. I used the Plugin Builder tool to create the base of the plugin. One of the functionalities I would like to implement is a Folder Dialog where one presses on a button, a folder dialog opens and one can mark one or more folders and their paths will be added to a list.

It seems to me that the available tutorials are contradicting each other and I do not really understand the separate parts of the main .py file of the tool and where I put what line of the code, except of course the imports.

This is the main .py file as created by the QGIS Plugin Builder:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication#, Qt
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QPushButton
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
from .resources import *
# Import the code for the dialog
from .test_tool_dialog import TestPluginDialog
import os.path


class TestPlugin:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'TestPlugin_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Test Plugin')

        # Check if plugin was started the first time in current QGIS session
        # Must be set in initGui() to survive plugin reloads
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('TestPlugin', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/test_tool/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Test Plugin'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True

    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Test Plugin'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started

        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = TestPluginDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result == QDialog.Accepted:
            pass
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
```

Here is a code snippet that I would like to somehow integrate in the code above (at least its functionality):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QFileDialog
from .ui_plugin_dialog import Ui_PluginDialog

class PluginDialog(QDialog, Ui_PluginDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PluginDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.showFolderDialog)

    def showFolderDialog(self):
        folder_dialog = QFileDialog(self)
        folder_dialog.setWindowTitle('Select Folders')
        folder_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
        folder_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)
        folder_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        folder_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.ReadOnly, False)
        folder_dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.AcceptMode, QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)

        if folder_dialog.exec_() == QFileDialog.Accepted:
            selected_folders = folder_dialog.selectedFiles()
            print('Selected Folders:', selected_folders)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a button first in the interface. This is usually done via the Qt designer. See for example here: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html , they also provide code for a file dialog.

Then, once you have the button and the function that runs on button click, add your code (the `showFolderDialog` method body) inside of it.

Comment: I did create the preliminary interface using QT Designer and I have created a designated button for the folder dialog. My problem is that I can't figure out where to put which line of code to "clicked.connect()" the button (let's call it 'testbutton') as well as its functionalities (the folder dialog).

Comment: It's in the tutorial, step 27 (the functionality) and step 28 (connecting to the button).